# I'd like to ask 'Block scope' about 'for'

Tags: javascript, scope, closures, lexical-scope, executioncontext

```js
let arr = []
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  arr.push(function() {
    console.log(i)
  })
}
arr[0]()
arr[1]()
arr[2]()
```

As far as I know, the function inside the block refers to its lexical environment.

In this case, it will refer to `i` of block `for (let i; …)`

When the loop ends, `i` remains 4.

So, I expected the console to say "3 3 3", but it says "0 1 2".

I concluded that this is because block `for` acts uniquely, and I wonder why such a result came about.

The expected behavior of block `for` is just like following two codes below, where the console says "3 3 3"

```js
let arr = []
{
  let i = 0
  while (i < 3) {
   arr.push(function () {
      console.log(i)
    })
  i++
  }
}
arr[0]()
arr[1]()
arr[2]()
```

or

```js
let arr = []
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  arr.push(function () {
    console.log(i)
  })
}
arr[0]()
arr[1]()
arr[2]()
```

Please tell me why the first case came out with the result "1 2 3".

Comment: The key is the use of `let` instead of `var`.

Comment: Why do you think it has anything to do with `for`? The only difference between the first and last example is `let` vs. `var`

Comment: you have three block scopes with `let`.

Comment: I can't get it. Do arr[0], arr[1], arr[2] refer to different "i"s?

Comment: When you declare a variable with `let` in the `for` loop header, each iteration has its own unique `i`.

Comment: Thanks. I owe you.

Comment: May I figuratively assume that "i" has been delivered as an argument?

Comment: The concept that the variables differ is too new to me.

Comment: (cause they are in the same block, have the same name)

Comment: Ah! I've got the meaning of "three block scopes" thanks